# Checking if all bits are set in a packed array in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I was looking through some SystemVerilog code, and I came across this expression for testing if all the bits in a packed array were set.

```
logic [SIZE-1:0]                   array;

// Bool we are evaluating:
array == '1;
```

Can someone explain to me how this works?  From what I have read, the `'1` is treated as a signed integer, so perhaps it is sign extended to be all 1's?  Just trying to make sense of this code snippet in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `'1` notation is a convenient way to set all bits to 1, even for a comparison as in your code.  Here is a small example to demonstrate:

```
module tb;

parameter SIZE = 3;
logic [SIZE-1:0] array;

initial begin
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) begin
        array = i;
        if (array == '1) begin
            $display("true  %b", array);
        end else begin
            $display("false %b", array);
        end
    end
end

endmodule
```

Prints:

```
false 000
false 001
false 010
false 011
false 100
false 101
false 110
true  111
```

IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 5.7.1 *Integer literal constants*, discusses this:

> An unsized single-bit value can be specified by preceding the
> single-bit value with an apostrophe ( ' ), but without the base
> specifier. All bits of the unsized value shall be set to the value of
> the specified bit.

Answer (score 1):

`'0`, `'1`, `'x` and `'z` are *fill* literals(See section *5.7.1 Integer literal constants* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)). Using the rules for expression bit widths (section *11.6.1*), these literals are filled to the determined width with all 0,1,x, or z's. In this case, to the width of `array`. In a self-determined context, i.e. stand-alone literal, they would just be a single digit.